# NodeJS express redirect page after login

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, routes, http-post

i have a weird problem and i could't solve it. First of all here is my code;

```
    exports.postLogin = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const inputs = await loginSchema.validateAsync(req.body);
    pool.connect(async (error, client, release) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.error("ERROR", error.stack);
      }
      const isExisting = await client.query(
        `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '${inputs.email}'`
      );
      if (isExisting.rowCount == 0) {
        release();
        return next(Boom.notFound("User not found!"));
      } else {
        const isCorrectPwd = await bcrypt.compare(
          inputs.password,
          isExisting.rows[0].password
        );
        if (!isCorrectPwd) {
          return next(Boom.unauthorized("Wrong password!"));
        }
        const accessToken = await signAccessToken(isExisting.rows[0].userid);
        const refreshToken = await signRefreshToken(isExisting.rows[0].userid);
        if (accessToken.length !== 0) {
          
          res.cookie("jwt", refreshToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 31556952000
          });
          
          // res.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
          res.redirect(303, '/');

        }

        
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.isJoi === true)
      return next(createError.BadRequest("Invalid username/password"));
    next(error);
  }
};
```

This is my login controller for post request. It works perfectly when i finalise it with res.json(accessToken,refreshToken). But i want to redirect user to homepage when login process succesfull. With this code nodejs tries to do POST request to "/" my homepage. I have no idea why my redirect request appear to be a post request. What's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance...

here is homepage controller;

```
exports.getHomePage = async (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("home", { path: "/" });
};
```

and here is it's route;

```
const express = require("express");
const protectController = require("../controller/protect");
const { verifyAccessToken } = require("../helpers/jwt_helper");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/secretpage", verifyAccessToken, protectController.getPage);
router.get("/", protectController.getHomePage);

module.exports = router;
```

and here is my terminal logs;

```
Express server listening on port 3000
Client connected to redis
Client connected to redis and ready to use
POST /auth/login 303 761.269 ms - 36
POST / 404 7.056 ms - 69
```

Comment: this is weird can we have a look on your other available route with ''/'' ?

Comment: sry to disappointed you but I wasn't able to figure it out... your code is pretty clean, did you also try with the full url just in case?

Comment: yes i tried with res.redirect(303,http://localhost:3000) and 301,302,307 status codes too. This is the first time that i have trouble with redirection process. i tried lots of combination but couldn't figure it out.